# How to display a list?

Tags: python, file-io

I'm building a simple function that works (delete the files). But In the end I want to return the list of the files that were effectively deleted.

This is the function:

```
def deleteFiles(files):
    # empty list
    RemovedFiles = list()

    for file in files:
        # Delete the file
        if os.remove(file):
            RemovedFiles.append(file)

    return RemovedFiles
```

I run this function with:

```
print deleteFiles([/home/xyz/xyz.zip])
```

This effectively deletes the xyz.zip but returns an empty list: `[]`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe once you do `os.remove(file)` the file no longer exists, and so it can't be added to the list. Try to get the name of the file before you remove it, and add the name to the list if it was removed.

Comment: @Oliver - Nonsense. The filename, `file`, is not the file on the filesystem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `os.remove` does not return anything.

You can however `try` and `except`:

```
for filename in filenames:
    try:
        # try to remove the file
        os.remove(filename)
    except OSError:
        pass
        # file not removed (maybe does not exist or is write-protected)
        # you may report an error here
    else:
        # this executes only if os.remove was successful
        RemovedFiles.append(filename)
```

Answer (score 3):

os.remove() returns None, so you never get to append to the list.

Comment: It's always good to have the manuals on docs.python.org open for reference. I usually use the big index to search for the functions I use. Or I use the Python shell and the `help` command to check the docstring of a functions.

Answer (score 3):

[`os.remove()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.remove#os.remove) doesn't return a value, so your `if` statement becomes effectively

```
if None:
    RemovedFiles.append(file)
```

On the other hand, it does throw an exception if it can't remove the file, so the following should work:

```
try:
    os.remove(file)
except OSError:
    pass
else:
    RemovedFiles.append(file)
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because os.remove() does not return anything. Your if condition evaluates to false.

Try this:

```
def deleteFiles(files):
# empty list
RemovedFiles = list()

for file in files:
    # Delete the file
    try:
        os.remove(file)
        RemovedFiles.append(file)
    except OSError:
        continue

return RemovedFiles
```

This should work